# Loop dentro do botao submeter

Tags: javascript, html, array, loop

Eu tenho o botao submeter que deve submeter a nota para uma turma de estudantes.
Mas quando clico no botao, ele submete somente a nota para o ultimo aluno na lista.
A lista de alunos e a lista de notas estao armazenadas no array students e no array grades. Eu estou usando um loop para isso, mas nao estou conseguindo fazer que toda a turma receba as notas. A minha funcao esta JS e o botao chama a funcao em HTML. Como faco para o loop adicionar a nota para todos os estudantes?

```
function addGradeToUsers(){
   showData();
   var students = [58686,58687, 392854];  // user Ids
   var orgUnitId= 167877;   //course number
   var gradeObjectId =111321; //grade name
   var gradeValue= [34,10,33];


    for(var i=0; i< students.length; i++){ 
    document.getElementById("PUTField").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("actionField").value = "/d2l/api/le/1.0/"+ orgUnitId +"/grades/"+ gradeObjectId+ "/values/"+ students[i] +"";
    document.getElementById("dataField").value = "{\n \"Comments\":{\"Content\":\"null\",\"Type\":\"Text\"},\n \"PrivateComments\":{\"Content\":\"null\",\"Type\":\"Text\"},\n \"GradeObjectType\": 1,\n\"PointsNumerator\":"+gradeValue[i]+" \n}";  
    } 
}
```

E aqui esta o codigo do botao:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for='contentType'>Importa notas</label>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Add Grade to Users" onclick='addGradeToUsers()'>
  </div>
```

Comment: Coloque o HTML onde estão esses elementos selecionados em `document.getElementById("PUTField")` e os outros. Suspeito que esteja duplicando esses id's e isso pode ser a causa do problema.

Comment: @Sam nao entendi o que tu quis dizer. O PUTField e um radiobutton slecionado quando clico para submeter as notas. O PUT vem da API.

Comment: Achei estranho o laço estar sempre selecionando os mesmos elementos.

Comment: @Sam "PUTField" significa que a API vai fazer um PUT. O PUT vai ser cada nota.

Comment: O `for` é assíncrono com qualquer coisa. Pelo que entendi, o resultado desse `for` vai ser aplicado apenas no último elemento da array, ou seja, no `392854`.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, tem uma API escutando o `checked` `true` e irá processar os valores alterados dos id's, é isso? Se for isso, não dá certo, porque o `for` é assíncrono com outros processos. Se for isso, creio que teria que usar um callback da API para processar cada coisa de uma vez.

Comment: @Sam Sim, e isso mesmo. Tenho uma API escutando o checked true e irá processar os valores alterados dos id's. Como faco para implementar o callback? alguma dica /

Comment: Só cheguei agora.. Cara, que API é esse?